# java, android and bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I want to write application on android and windows which will use bluetooth. In short my app (on android) will exchange data with another app (on windows) trough bluetooth. I see that there is good bluetooth support on android so I think that there will be no problems on android side. My problem is windows side. I have laptop (asus f3sg) with bluetooth adapter and Windows 7. Is in java SE any library which I can use to develop on Windows 7 apps using bluetooth? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you even look it up at all? http://www.google.com/#hl=en&cp=17&gs_id=1r&xhr=t&q=java+windows+bluetooth&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=java+windows+blue&aq=0v&aqi=g-v1g-b3&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=b4e358c040803e1f&biw=1680&bih=912

Comment: Yeah, I google about that but I dont get anything clearly and I want to hear what will say people who have some experience with that things.

Comment: @klemens, Have you implemented Android bluetooth share by using bluecove/obex,if so let me guide to implement on android.i am facing problem up that saying bluetooth device not found/ bluecove nativelibray mismatch and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [BlueCove](http://bluecove.org/). I have used BlueCove successfully with earlier version of Windows. They have release a snapshot ([2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.63](http://snapshot.bluecove.org/distribution/download/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.63/)) that appears to work for Windows 7.

Comment: @Richard Povinelli, I tried to use bluecove api in android, but it doesn't work. I added bluecove.jar(snapshot) and bluecove-gpl(snapshot version), i also added libbluecove.so at libs/armeabi. but it shows me an error that bluecove native library mismatch version. and often that while changing jar of different versions it shows me  No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/skipping init

Comment: @Senthil Mg: I have used BlueCove only on the Windows side, not on the Android. I just checked [BlueCove](http://www.bluecove.org/), they do not provide Android versions.